# XSLT - combline template match

Tags: xml, xslt

brain fart i figured out the issue my fault thank you!

Comment: Can you edit your question to include your XSLT? (You could probably remove the `file-prefix` variable to save space). As wonderful as http://xsltransform.net/ is, it does go down for long periods at a time, which would make this question hard to answer if it did. Thanks!

Comment: i have done as you said! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First things first: This Stylesheet is pretty complicated and brings so many "problems" with it. Please do me a favor and ask yourself, if this is the right way to go. I doubt it.

**Fix/Solution:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:java="org.dita.dost.util.GenUtils" exclude-result-prefixes="java">
    <xsl:param name="outdir.subsidiary"/>

    <xsl:variable name="file-prefix">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="string-length($outdir.subsidiary) &gt; 0 and not(substring($outdir.subsidiary,string-length($outdir.subsidiary))='/')and not(substring($outdir.subsidiary,string-length($outdir.subsidiary))='\')">
                <xsl:value-of select="translate($outdir.subsidiary,
                    '\/=+|?[]{}()!#$%^&amp;*__~`;:.,-abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ',
                    '//=+|?[]{}()!#$%^&amp;*__~`;:.,-abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ')"/><xsl:text>/</xsl:text>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="translate($outdir.subsidiary,
                    '\/=+|?[]{}()!#$%^&amp;*__~`;:.,-abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ',
                    '//=+|?[]{}()!#$%^&amp;*__~`;:.,-abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ')"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>

        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:variable>


    <xsl:template match="*[(@class) and not(contains(@class,' asc/pnum ')) and not(contains(@class, ' third/fig-meta ')) and not(contains(@class,' asc/linum ')) and not(contains(@class, ' topic/image ')) and not(contains(@class,' asc/pgroup '))]">
        <xsl:variable name="generalize" select="substring-before(substring-after(@class,'/'),' ')" />
        <xsl:element name="{$generalize}">
            <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="data" priority="2"/>
    <xsl:template match="image">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />
            <xsl:apply-templates select="../data" mode="map" />
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*[contains(@class,' third/fig-meta ')]" mode="map">
        <alt><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" /></alt>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Single breakdown**

XSLT decides on his own, what template matches my current to process node. Internal a priority will be generated depending on complexity-rules and accuracy of match-expression. Based on this background wrong templates were executed and your output was not like expected. You have to set a priority for templates on your own. Many times this is an indicator to do it wrong.

`xsl:copy-of` will just copy without evaluate any templates. In your example you want to execute the last template to rename `data` into `alt`. => `<xsl:apply-templates select="../data"/>`.

`<xsl:template match="*[contains(@class,' asc/fig-meta ')]">` this matches nothing. Changed to `<xsl:template match="*[contains(@class,' third/fig-meta ')]" mode="baum">`. [see "asc" vs "third"]

`mode="map"` is required, otherwise the template for remove `data` will be executed and no output will occur.

So far my two cents on your question.

Comment: Hi thanks for your help it cleared things up a lot but unfortunately I dont think it will give me intended results, see updated: [http://xsltransform.net/ejivdGY/4] the issue is because the first template match (generalize) you have excluded the third/fig-meta elements but i need those to be transformed as well to data elements

Comment: There is a separate template defined for ` third/fig-meta ` to create `alt`-tags. Sorry i don't get your exactly problem and background. Maybe you state your requirements and the xslt could be refactored.